# Jenkins in ubuntu

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using docker-compose to mount a volume on an image. I have the container running, but not able to pull the image in the browser.

Docker-compose has these below lines -

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
    jenkins:     
         image: image_name
         restart: unless-stopped
         volumes:
                - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock      
                - /home/gp_oes/project/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home                    
         ports:
                - 8080
```

Comment: What is your ```image_name``` ?

Comment: Also, can you post the error if it is due to timeout or some vpn related incase if it is in private n/w

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to download the official image of ubuntu (https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins)  which was deprecated since last 2 years.

Please check with the community image of jenkins (https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins)

if  it is not the case please provide error with command and image name also to give better understanding of the question.